# I am trying to install plugins on a local Wordpress install

Tags: wordpress

I can't install any plugins through WordPress on the local install. Up until now I have manually dropped them in but I added the Developer plugin and need it to be able to do it itself.

Installing any plugin I get the following error:

> Unable to locate WordPress Content directory (wp-content).

For any of the plugins related to the Developer Plugin I get the error:

> ERROR: Failed to install plugin: Please ensure the file system is writeable

I am running XAMPP on a OSX Yosemite. Help on either of the problems would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: yes,
My man
way to go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with setting wp-content and wp-content/plugins permissions to 777.

Check here http://osxdaily.com/2011/02/21/change-file-permissions-mac/
Set 'everyone' to 'Read & Write'.

As for now script don't have permissions to write in wp-content folder nor sub-folders.

Comment: just did that, it still cant find the wp-content folder though for whatever reason. I'm halfway there though, thank you

Comment: Adding this line to my wp-config.php worked.

define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');

Answer (score 5):

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

did it for me

Answer (score 0):

Step by Step instructions

1. Go to the directory xampp/htdocs/wordpress
2. Edit wp-cong.php file
3. Add the below line in the file and save it

   *define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');*
4. Restart Apache Server